# How to Convert the last digit of a number to a char and display it on LCD?

Tags: c, stm8

I recently got a STM8 MCU and it has the built in function `LCD_GLASS_DisplayString("STRING")`

The problem with that function is, as you can see below, that I cannot directly display an integer on it:

```
void LCD_GLASS_DisplayString(uint8_t* ptr)
{
  uint8_t i = 0x01;

    LCD_GLASS_Clear();
  /* Send the string character by character on lCD */
  while ((*ptr != 0) & (i < 8))
  {
    /* Display one character on LCD */
    LCD_GLASS_WriteChar(ptr, FALSE, FALSE, i);

    /* Point on the next character */
    ptr++;

    /* Increment the character counter */
    i++;
  }
}
```

How could I modify it so I could send integers directly? Also, I'm not sure I can use any libraries, so just pure C would help.

I was thinking of something like this, but it didn't work:

```
void LCD_GLASS_DisplayINT(uint16_t integer)
{
  uint8_t i = 0x01;

    LCD_GLASS_Clear();
  /* Send the string character by character on lCD */
  while ((integer != 0) & (i < 8))
  {
    /* Display one number on LCD */
    LCD_GLASS_WriteChar("0" + integer%10, FALSE, FALSE, i);

    /* Point on the next number*/
    integer=integer/10;

    /* Increment the character counter */
    i++;
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to make it work? I need to either make a function to display the integers or a way to convert them to strings before I send them over to the LCD. The code is pure C, as what I'm programming are pure drivers right now.

Comment: `(*ptr != 0) & (i < 8)` looks like nonsense. Is the `&` intentional? If it is, then stop writing weird code like that...

Comment: Note: `LCD_GLASS_DisplayINT(0)` prints nothing.  Cosider `do { ... } while (integer > 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not far off with `"0" + integer%10` - but you need to treat it as a character - `'0' + integer%10` - and you need to pass `LCD_GLASS_WriteChar` a **pointer** to this character.

One way to do this is:

```
char* digits = "0123456789";
LCD_GLASS_WriteChar(&digits[integer % 10], FALSE, FALSE, i);
```

---

Also, your loop condition - `while ((integer != 0) & (i < 8))` should not use bitwise and (`&`), but rather logical and (`&&`).

```
while ((integer != 0) && (i < 8))
```

Comment: Yep, it worked!! Just a problem now that I didn't have while displaying strings, the number is displayed backwards

30 will be 03 and so on

Comment: :) There are a few solutions for this - the standard way is to just use a function like `sscanf` to convert the number into a string, but you might not have access to this functionality on your embedded system.. you can "flip" the number numerically (`123` -> `321`) and then print it.. or you can use a static buffer of up to eight characters, write your digits to the buffer starting from its end character, and then print the buffer from the last digit you parsed onwards.

Comment: I flipped the number, it was easier to code. Thank you so much for your help! <3

Comment: Agree about _should_, yet `while ((integer != 0) & (i < 8))` functions the same.  It may emit tigher code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to store the digits in a buffer to get the left-to-right order. On a microcontroller you'll probably want to allocate that buffer in `.bss` so that it doesn't take up stack. Use `static` to make that happen. For a 16 bit number you'll have at most 5 digits + null term, so:

```
static char buf[5+1] = {0};
```

The conversion is essentially the code you've written, except you mixed up `'0'` and `"0"`:

```
for(uint8_t i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  buf[5-i-1] = val%10 + '0';
  val/=10;
}
```

Note that this code always leaves item `buf[5]` untouched and leaves a zero null terminator there.

Complete code with tests in standard C. Obviously drop `puts` for your custom LCD routine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void display_int (uint16_t val)
{
  static char buf[5+1] = {0};
  char* p;
  
  for(uint8_t i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
    buf[5-i-1] = val%10 + '0';
    val/=10;
  }
  
  // trim leading zeroes
  for(p=buf; *p!='\0'; p++)
  {
    if(*p!='0' ||    // stop looking at first non zero or 
       p[1]=='\0')   // in case there is only one zero character
      break;
  }
  
  puts(p); // use whatever string printing routine you got
}

int main (void)
{
  display_int(0);
  display_int(5);
  display_int(666);
  display_int(12345);
}
```

Division on STM8 is very expensive. We can optimize the code a bit by not filling up the whole buffer if we don't have to. This saves us several `DIV` calls. Optimized version, faster but harder to read:

```
void display_int (uint16_t val)
{
  static char buf[5+1] = {0};
  char* p;
  char* start;
  
  for(uint8_t i=0;;i++)
  {
    buf[5-i-1] = val%10 + '0';
    val/=10;
    if(val==0)
    {
      start = &buf[5-i-1];
      break;
    }
  }
  
  // trim leading zeroes
  for(p=start; *p!='\0'; p++)
  {
    if(*p!='0' ||    // stop looking at first non zero or 
       p[1]=='\0')   // in case there is only one zero character
      break;
  }
  puts(p); // use whatever string printing routine you got
}
```